# Angular JS Unit Testing: search module error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

In the package.json file I have following dependencies :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.7.7",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.4.1",
    "protractor": "^4.0.9"
  }
```

And bower.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-loader": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.5.0",
    "html5-boilerplate": "^5.3.0"
  }
```

If I perform the command `karma start karma.conf.js` I'll have an error like this:

```
     Error: Cannot find module 'jasmine-core'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
        at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
        at initJasmine (C:\Users\Ema_Holub\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma-jasmine\lib\index.js:8:42)
        at Array.invoke (C:\Users\Ema_Holub\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:75:15)
        at Injector.get (C:\Users\Ema_Holub\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:48:43)
        at C:\Users\Ema_Holub\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:143:20
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Server._start (C:\Users\Ema_Holub\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:142:21)
        at Injector.invoke (C:\Users\Ema_Holub\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:75:15)
        at Server.start (C:\Users\Ema_Holub\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:103:18)
        at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\Ema_Holub\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\cli.js:280:26)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ema_Holub\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\bin\karma:3:23)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And if you do 'npm install jasmine-core' and then try it, does it work?

Comment: I did it. But I have this error anyway

Comment: And an 'npm install' after that?

Comment: Yes, I performed it

Comment: Hi! Try deleting your node_modules folder, then execute "npm cache clear", finally execute "npm install".